# how to get physical constant in scipy in cgs unit?

Tags: python, scipy, constants

I was wondering how do I get some physical constants from scipy.constants in cgs unit.

for example: if I want thomson cross section constant from scipy I do,

```
constants.value(u'Thomson cross section')
6.6524587158e-29
```

But this is built in SI unit. Also it does not show me the unit that comes with it. I want to import it in cgs:
Is there any command in scipy that will allow me select the unit as well? Maybe something like the following:

```
constants.value(u'Thomson cross section').in_units_of(cm**2)
```

Your suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: [Reading the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/constants.html) it's easy to get the unit, but there seems to be no support for conversions except maybe for temperature and optics.

Answer (score 1):

From browsing the `constants.py` file (documentation) I deduce that I can get:

```
In [183]: constants.value('Thomson cross section')
Out[183]: 6.6524587158e-29
In [184]: constants.unit('Thomson cross section')
Out[184]: 'm^2'
In [187]: constants.precision('Thomson cross section')
Out[187]: 1.367915290986615e-09
```

This value is in a dictionary:

```
In [196]: constants.physical_constants['Thomson cross section']
Out[196]: (6.6524587158e-29, 'm^2', 9.1e-38)
```

See the `scipy.constants.codata.py` file for more information.

I don't see any code in the `constants.py` file to do unit conversions.  Guess you'll have to do that yourself.